# Upload a File from HTML form using PostAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to simply upload a file to server using WebAPI. I want to call the WebApi in my MVC HomeController. When I use the WebAPI directly it uploads files perfectly however when I want to call the WebAPI within my Controller using PostAsync, it does not send the file to the api for some reason.

This is the action in my MVC Controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Upload Files";
        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();

            string FullUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + "/api/values";
            StringContent httpcontent = new StringContent(upload.FileName);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(FullUrl, httpcontent);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpResponseMessage>();

        }


        return View();
    }
```

This is the .cshtml file:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="/Home/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div>
    <label for="upload">Choose a File</label>
    <input name="upload" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Finally this is the WebApi Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostFile()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, where are you having a problem? Please don't just ask for a solution, show us what you have done (check), show us where you are having a specific problem (missing), and then ask a specific question about that error (missing)

Comment: Have you debugged to see where the error occurs?

Comment: I don't get any errors as I mentioned: it does not send the file to the api for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When content post by the form, it's setup multipart/form-data content type to the request.
You can try to setup request content type to **multipart/form-data** explicitly.

```
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new StreamContent(upload.InputStream);
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = upload.ContentType;
requestContent.Add(fileContent, upload.FileName, upload.FileName);

client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);
```